# I've cloned a .NET repo written in C#, how do I run it on a mac?

Tags: asp.net, .net, git, macos

Question title pretty much says it. I've got the folder containing all files & folders, how do I run the app locally? - (similar to how you'd boot up a rails server & view it in browser).

Comment: push the directory to a repo that bot your PC and Mac can see.

Comment: I don't have a PC, and I'm looking for a more specific answer. I've never worked with .net before.

Comment: .NET traditionally runs on Windows, though there are [various](http://www.mono-project.com/) [attempts](https://xamarin.com/) to make it more cross-platform and large parts of the platform were [recently open sourced](http://www.dotnetfoundation.org/). Arbitrary .NET applications aren't guaranteed (or in many cases even expected) to work on non-Windows platforms. Does this one have any documentation suggesting otherwise?

Comment: The newer version of ASP.NET support OSX/Linux better than @chris suggests, but depending on the repo you're cloning the version could be an issue as he suggests. Google will help if you know what version your running, but starting "a RAILS server" throws me for a ... what? http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/tutorials/your-first-mac-aspnet.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just got this working!

I installed mono and the command line tools and got lucky

Steps:

Install Mono http://www.mono-project.com/download/

Install DNVM Command Line

```
$ curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aspnet/Home/dev/dnvminstall.sh | DNX_BRANCH=dev sh && source ~/.dnx/dnvm/dnvm.sh
$ dnvm upgrade -r coreclr
$ dnvm upgrade -r mono
```

Go to your app the folder with project.json (or if you don't have one use the Yo Generator) and Run these commands

```
$ dnu restore
$ dnx web
```

This should start the web application

Visit the site:

```
http://localhost:5000
```

Please let me know if this works

I've made these notes [Running a .NET Web Application on OSX](https://github.com/stujo/asp.net-5-getting-started-osx/blob/master/Running-NET-On-OSX.md)

[Based on this exploration ... me rambling too much to be useful](https://github.com/stujo/asp.net-5-getting-started-osx/blob/master/README.md)

Let me know if it works for you, if not I'll try again

Answer (score 0):

Use xsp in place of IIS and use xbuild in place of msbuild.